# Add and remove for ObservableCollection from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created the ObservableCollection, which works with bindings, etc. Now I have a problem, I can't access it from other classes. Tried most things but probably missing some obvious things.

```
public MyFavorites()
{
    ObservableServers = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
}

private ObservableCollection<Server> _myListOfServersObjects;
public ObservableCollection<Server> ObservableServers
{
    get => _myListOfServersObjects;
    set
    {
        if (_myListOfServersObjects != value)
        {
            _myListOfServersObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ObservableServers");
        }
    }
}
```

full code: https://pastebin.com/KLFHwhKg

so i`m trying to add: https://pastebin.com/p7dBDcXq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get flagged because it's a very broad topic and not related to a specific issue. The general way you solve this is to create an interface such as the following:

```
public interface IServerCollection
{
    IList<Server> ObservableServers { get; }
}
```

Notice that I've changed ObservableServers from an ObservableCollection<> to an IList<>. From the perspective of the other parts of your application the actual implementation doesn't matter, so choose the most basic interface object that will fulfill their needs. The actual implementation class fills in the details:

```
public class ServerCollection : IServerCollection
{
    private IList<Server> _myListOfServersObjects = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
    public IList<Server> ObservableServers {get => _myListOfServersObjects;}
}
```

So somewhere in your application something creates an instance of type ServerCollection, and it then gets passed in as an IList to whatever needs it e.g.:

```
public IServerCollection ServerCollection {get; private set;}

public MyFavorites(IServerCollection serverCollection)
{
    ServerCollection = serverCollection;
}
```

This is known broadly as "Inversion of Control", and the actual passing of the interface instance into your class is known as "Dependency Injection". There are heaps of resources about both of these around the net, they're well worth reading up on. They solve a lot of problems but they also create a new one: you find yourself passing lots of these interface references around and storing them at multiple levels of your application. Thus, in a real application you typically use a dependency injection framework to largely automate the work for you, and in the case of .NET the package of choice 9 times out of 10 is [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).